# emacs how to refresh buffer and preserve highlighting - especially for logs

Tags: regex, emacs

I am often parsing log files, which I help visualize by highlighting specific char sequences via `M-s h r` <kbd>+</kbd> `regex`, aka the command `highlight-regexp` or `hi-lock-face-buffer`. Sometimes I will need to regenerate the log file, which is done via the `C-x C-v` or `find-alternate-file` command.  Unfortunately, the regeneration also loses all of my highlighting.

**TLDR**
Is there a way to regenerate my buffer file while maintaining all of the highlighting?

**Update**
I am using `text-mode`, and the regexes vary widely depending on my task and the log file. I would like something that carries over all of my highlighting to the refreshed buffer. Does something already exist?

**Answer:**
Even better than maintaining highlights after a refresh, the selected answer uses an `add-hook` to create a highlighting scheme for a particular log. Additionally, each log can have different highlight schemes. The result is an automated highlighting scheme that matches a particular log file's name, with the ability to toggle the schemes of various highlights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add-hook that:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^\\([^,]*\\)," 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))))
```

What regexp you'd like to highlight? If You are using several regexps depending on the log, it might be possible to hook them all. Or you might program the condition: which regexp to hightlight:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (condition)
                ;; condition true:
                (font-lock-add-keywords nil '((regexp1 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
              ;; condition false:
              (font-lock-add-keywords nil   '((regexp2 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
              )
            ))
```

Also if you control the generation of logs you can generate the hightlight rules in the first line:

```
# -*- eval: (highlight-regexp REGEXP) -*-
```

(assuming # is the comment char in your log).

**Edit**:

Here's defun which toggles hightlighting for `TestQueryLogic` or `invoking fork-join` and `testGudermann`:

```lisp
(defun testing-MapAppLog.txt ()
  "Toggle highlighting `TestQueryLogic' or `invoking fork-join' and `testGudermann'."
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ((get this-command 'state)
    (highlight-regexp "TestQueryLogic"     font-lock-variable-name-face)
    (highlight-regexp "invoking fork-join" font-lock-type-face)
    (unhighlight-regexp "testGudermann")
    (message "Highlighting: TestQueryLogic, invoking fork-join")
    (put this-command 'state nil))
   (t
    (unhighlight-regexp "TestQueryLogic")
    (unhighlight-regexp "invoking fork-join")
    (highlight-regexp "testGudermann" font-lock-preprocessor-face)
    (message "Highlighting: testGudermann")
    (put this-command 'state t))))
```

So call it once to hightlight `TestQueryLogic`, `invoking fork-join`, call it again to hightlight `testGudermann` instead. You can bind to a key:

```
(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "M-s t") 'testing-MapAppLog.txt)
```

and press that once or twice depending on what you'd like to highlight.

Comment: I updated my question. Does this mean that I have to hard code each regexp that I want to highlight into the `add-hook` above? If so, I am not sure if this is convenient. The highlighting that I use is variable. For example, I may be debugging the `FooModule` one day, so I highlight all `FooModule` terms, but another day I may debug `BarModule`, so I do not highlight any `FooModule` terms but `BarModule` terms instead. Is there something that will save my highlight regexps, and reload them when I refresh the buffer?

Comment: @Lucas: think of a smart way to notify emacs of that. For example you can make emacs choose regexp to highlight based on the location of the module, name, extension, first line. Also you might write smarter regexps to highlight, so that all works with both modules. Finally you can write two hooks and comment one of them in your `.emacs` depending on what you work on at the moment.

Comment: I think I am understanding. So, instead of running `M-s h r` + `regexp`, I add the regexp to the `add-hook` above in my `init.el`? So when I am parsing my log file, and see a term that I want to highlight, let's say `interesting foo string`, then I add it to the field `regexp1` above and refresh the log file? Is this the recommended usage scenario?

Comment: Well, emacs is about automating things. So typing regexp manually again and again is certainly not a recommended usage. Adding `add-hook` in `init.el` is a most natural way of customizing the mode. If you give real examples of what you'd like to highlight and what are the typical names of your logs, I might help you with that.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the offer! The log is named `MapAppLog.txt`, and I would like to highlight the regexps `TestQueryLogic` and `invoking fork-join` when testing the queries logic, and I would like to highlight the regexp `testGudermann` when testing my Gudermann function. The highlighting should be exclusive - when testing the queries logic I do not want to highlight `testGudermann`, and vice-versa. Also, I usually highlight `TestQueryLogic` in `yellow`, and `testGudermann` in `green`(although I can probably figure out how to automate the color preferences).

Comment: The log highlighting is working great. Thanks @Adobe!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `C-x C-v` which basically says "throw away current buffer and use thise other file instead" an has hence no hope of preserving transient info such as your highlighting patterns, you want to use `revert-buffer`, or maybe even `auto-revert-mode` or `auto-revert-tail-mode`.