# emacs: selectively choose on which buffers to execute an add-hook, using regexp

Tags: emacs

How can I selectively get the file/buffer name to add to my hook? In the example below, I want to satisfy `condition` so that it will execute my command only when I open particularly named files, like "testLog.txt".

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (condition)
                ;; condition true:
                (font-lock-add-keywords nil '((regexp1 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
              ;; condition false:
              (font-lock-add-keywords nil   '((regexp2 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
              )
            ))
```

I tried using `(string= (buffer-name) "contacts.txt")` in place of `(condition)`, but I would like to match more file names.

Any suggestions?

This question is a followup to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606180/emacs-how-to-refresh-buffer-and-preserve-highlighting-especially-for-logs)

Comment: If you really received an error message `file mode specification error: (void-function condition)`, then you probably did *not* use `(string= (buffer-name) "contacts.txt")` becasue `(string= (buffer-name) "contacts.txt")` is correct.  Perhaps you have the `text-mode-hook` function elsewhere in your user-customization files.  For you to have received an error message `. . . (void-function condition)`, you most certainly used `condition` as a function -- just like your example `text-mode-hook` above uses `(condition)` as a function.

Comment: Yes, this was really strange, but I figured it out! I had used the original code above with the `condition` in place and evaluated my buffer (`init.el`). Even though I changed it, the hook was not removed. It seems that I was only adding more hooks be redefining the method above. Anyway, restarting emacs fixed everything. So, my original solution works, although yours is much cleaner.Thanks!

Comment: Also, I reworded the question to fit the solution, making this post more coherent. Hopefully this will help others more. The original problem is different from what I thought it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?  The regexp can be a file-type extension, or a full file name (without the path), or a buffer-name.

```lisp
(defvar text-mode-buffer-regexp '(
  "\\.txt" "\\.md" "\\.pm" "\\.conf" "\\.htaccess" "\\.html" "\\.tex" "\\.el"
  "\\.yasnippet" "user_prefs" "\\.shtml" "\\.cgi" "\\.pl" "\\.js" "\\.css"
  "\\*eshell\\*")
"Regexp of file / buffer names that will be matched using `regexp-match-p` function.")

;; https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
;; `regexp-match-p` function modified by @sds on stackoverflow
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343715/2112489
(defun regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t)) ; small optimization
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (if (regexp-match-p text-mode-buffer-regexp (buffer-name))
      ;; condition true:
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil
        '((regexp1 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
    ;; condition false:
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
      '((regexp2 1 'font-lock-function-name-face))) ) ))
```

Comment: You can unify your two font-lock calls as: `(font-lock-add-keywords nil \`((,(if (regexp-match-p text-mode-buffer-regexp (buffer-name)) regexp1 regexp2) 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))`.